# grunt-import does not run tasks after completing

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to use the grunt-import plugin. Everything is working fine except that it doesn't run the defined tasks after it completes. I'm trying to get it to run my uglify:dist task once it completes. The current documentation explains how to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

See the documentation for the grunt-import task here: https://github.com/marcinrosinski

Here are the related grunt tasks in my gruntfile.js

```
import: {
  dist: {
    src:  '<%= pkg.assets %>/compile/js/app.js',
    dest: '<%= pkg.assets %>/js/app.js'
  },
  tasks: ['uglify:dist']
},

uglify: {
  dist: {
    files: { 
      '<%= pkg.assets %>/js/app.min.js': ['<%= pkg.assets %>/js/app.js'] 
    }
  }
},

watch: {
  grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },

  js: {
    files: ['<%= pkg.assets %>/compile/js/app.js'],
    tasks: ['import'],
    options: {
      livereload: true
    }
  },

  sass: {
    files: '<%= pkg.assets %>/compile/scss/**/*.scss',
    tasks: ['sass'],
    options: {
      interrupt: true,
      livereload: true
    }
  },

  assemble: {
    files: '<%= pkg.app %>/assemble/**/*.hbs',
    tasks: ['assemble'],
    options: {
      livereload: true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to register import:dist and uglify:dist as a new grunt task.

in your gruntfile, add:

```
grunt.registerTask("dist", ["import:dist", "uglify:dist"]);
```

Then in terminal, type `grunt dist`, and it should run both tasks, import:dist first, and uglify:dist second.

**EDIT:**

Also be sure you are adding grunt-contrib-uglify to your project. It won't run if you forgot to do so.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I had only registered the tasks like this:  grunt.registerTask("dist", ["import", "uglify"]); So, do you have to register the targets in the tasks as well?

Comment: Yes, unless the grunt task has one it includes by default (some do some don't). Also, you can make many different subtasks, like a dev version, etc.. 

One more thing: grunt.registerTask("dist", ["import:dist"]); might have been enough as well, as you specify "tasks: ['uglify:dist']" in import:dist task.

Comment: Interesting. The Import task was running just fine though, it just didn't seem to want to run the uglify task defined in the import task. All very good to know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just confirmed that that only specifying the import:dist task was enough to make it all work.